# ¿Cómo puedo dar o llamar los estilos CSS a una tabla HTML definida en en PHP?

Tags: php, html, css

```
<?php
require('../logica/conexion.php');
 ?>
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="es">
 <head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <title>Comunidad</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/estilos.css">
   <script src="../Jquery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/script.js"> </script>
 </head>
<body>
<h1>Editar</h1>

<?php
$db = new conexion();
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING |E_PARSE);
$mensaje=$_GET["mensaje"];

$result=$db->query($mensaje);


if (    $info_campo = mysqli_fetch_fields($result)) {

  $col=mysqli_num_fields($result);
$num=$col-1; ?>
<center>
  <?php
  $table ="<table id=\"tab\" border=\"1px solid #000\" width=\"600\">";

     $table .="<tr>";
        foreach ($info_campo as $valor) {
          $table .= "<th>".$valor->name."</th>";
  }
  $table .= "</tr>";
        $a=0;
       while ($fila=mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
  $table .="<tr aling=\"center\">";
   for ($i=0; $i <=$num; $i++) {

    $table .= "<td>".$fila[$i]."</td>";
   }
  $a++;
    $table .= "</tr>";
       }

             $table .="</table>";

echo $table;
 }

?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: es mi impresion o la ultima llave antes del echo esta sobrando

Comment: no esta sobrando solo que es el cierre de un if donde muestro la tabla

Comment: cuando haces esto [class='tab'] estas dandole un estilo definido de algun css que debes haber importado o bien de un script previamente definido, asi que no comprendo del todo que necesitas hacer o que error te sale ?

Comment: Como yo lo veo lo que puedes hacer es declarar clases a tu tabla con los estilos que necesitas ya predefinidos

Comment: pues intente hacerlo definiendo lo directamente en el css  ejemplo

Comment: table{
  font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin: 45px;
  width: auto;
  text-align: center;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  float:center;
}

Comment: pero pues no me funciona también intente llamar la clase asi  class\"tab\" tampoco me funciono el width si me lo reconoce

Answer (score 1):

Las hojas de estilos CSS están relacionadas con los documentos HTML y tienen poca relación con el lenguaje de programación PHP. En tu caso estás usando PHP para generar un documento HTML, por lo que ese HTML es el que debe ser abordado y no el lenguaje PHP en sí.

En tu código el problema que estás sufriendo, aparentemente, es debido a que no estás usando correctamente el atributo `border` de la etiqueta `<table>`:

```
$table = "<table id=\"tab\" border=\"1px solid #000\" width=\"600\">";
```

Al ejecutar el script ese código PHP genera el siguiente HTML:

```
<table id="tab" border="1px solid #000" width="600">
```

El uso del [atributo `border` de la etiqueta `<table>` está obsoleto](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement/border) y debe hacerse a través de estilos CSS:

> Syntax: **`border`** is a string representing the width of
>   the border in pixels.

En castellano:

> Sintaxis: **`border`** es una cadena representando el ancho del borde en puntos.

Por lo que todo aquello que vaya más allá de proporcionar un número, no será interpretado por el navegador, de modo que la forma correcta sería:

```
<table id="tab" style="border: 1px solid #000; width: 600px;">
```

Answer (score 0):

La forma normal o por defecto de hacer esto es estableciendo ya el fichero css, en tu caso `estilos.css` y en el momento de cargar la tabla con php esta utilizara ya el estilo predefinido.Es una forma que funciona, de hecho yo la utilizo y el estilo se aplica, incluso elementos cargados con AJAX al momento tambien se les aplica el estilo establecido en el fichero.

Por lo tanto mi recomendacion es la siguiente:

- Una vez cargada la tabla comprueba con las herramientas del desarollados de tu navegador si las etiquetas se generan de forma correcta en tu fichero
- Ya que tienes una `ID` utilízala:

  ```
  #tab{
      border:1px solid red;
  }
  ```

También seria posible añadir el Style a la tabla  directamente en el html pero es recomendable utilizar la otra forma para tener una mejor organización de la pagina

Comment: gracias  pues no pude hacerlo por css  me toco agregar el estilo directamente en html

Comment: Comprueba con las herramientas de desarollador que los elementos HTML generados por el codigo php se generen de forma correcta. Y que el fichero de `estilos.css` este bien adjuntado,por ejemplo si un `body{background-color:red}` se aplica o no ya que es muy raro que no funcione. Por defecto podrias hacer uso de `!important` para obligar a aplicar ese atributo en concreto pero aun asi no veo el que  puede estar contrarestandolo si lo pones por defecto